# Can't require 'osx/cocoa' after RubyCocoa installation

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoa, rvm

I've tried moving files around and performing various un/installations and still cannot seem to get RubyCocoa to load when I do require 'osx/cocoa'.  I even found the native apple version of RubyCocoa and those files won't load either.  I've hit a dead end trying to determine how I can get it to work and was really hoping someone could help.  I'm interested in testing its functionality and possibly writing some applescripts, using Ruby, but until I overcome this issue I'm completely stuck.  Thanks!

Extra points if you can figure out how I can install RubyCocoa with RVM.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS X Maverics, OS-embedded Ruby 1.8 (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby`) is required to use `require osx/cocoa`. Specify the path instead of using other versions of Ruby that are installed with rbenv or rvm.

Please note that this solution is temporal because the version of Ruby 1.8 has been removed in Yosemite and `require osx/cocoa` is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the game but this gist will help https://gist.github.com/nsforge/6861400.